# How to center using sticky?

Tags: python, tkinter

For any label, say `Label`, I want to center it using sticky.
Therefore I tried,

```
Label.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'center') #using tkinter
```

Which is wrong, so how would I get this right?

Comment: By default it is center without specifying `sticky` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widgets by default are centered in a grid cell. You should not provide a value for the `sticky` option, or you can provide an empty string, which will have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I was able to solve this with the following.

```
Label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = tkinter.N + tkinter.S + tkinter.E + tkinter.W);
#The N, S, E, and W represent north, south, east, and west.
#if you import tkinter as tk, then this could look much cleaner
```

Comment: You can also just use the literal string "nsew" since that's all that the constants are.